# In a UserFactory, I need to write a state method that attaches the user being created (or created) to a many to many "role" object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I would want to write something like this:

```
class UserFactory extends Factory
{

   public function withRoles(array $roles) {
        $factory->state(function (array $attributes) use ($roles)  {
                     $user = User::find($attributes['id']);
                     $roles = Role::whereIn('title', $roles)->get();
                     $user->roles()->attach($roles);
    
                     return $user;
        });
   }
```

Unfortunately, `id` is not available in this `$attributes` nor, I guess, in the state methods of a factory.

What could I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback function in the configure function of the UserFactory:

```
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Configure the model factory.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterMaking(function (User $user) {
            
        })->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
            //
        });
    }
 
    // ...
}
```

This would do it every time you use the create / make UserFactory functions.

Alternatively you may use the built in ->hasAttached() or ->has() method e.g.

```
$user = User::factory()
            ->count(3)
            ->has($roles)
            ->create();
```

This is all outlined pretty well in the Laravel documentation for factories: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#factory-states

Comment: "This would do it every time you use the create / make UserFactory functions.
" : yes but it makes the use of a state function irrelevant, right? And the other solution you provide also eludes the use of a state function. My deduction is: we can't use a state function in this context, right?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler For your example you should just be using the built in ->has() method, there is no need to add the withRoles or state function.  Laravel has these methods to work the tables the factory has relationships with, the state functions themselves seem to be primarily focused on altering the attributes directly on the model factory, not the related tables.